# error number -1708 While splitting a string

Tags: applescript

I have the following function that does string splitting:

```
on splitText(aString, delimiter)
    set retVal to {}
    set prevDelimiter to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {delimiter}
    set retVal to every text item of aString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevDelimiter
    return retVal
end splitText
```

When used by itself, it works ok

log splitText("http://google.com|/Users/pistacchio/Desktop/google.jpg", "|")

But when I use it within the context I need, I get a `-1708` error

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    repeat with row in linesToPrint
        log splitText("http://google.com|/Users/pistacchio/Desktop/google.jpg", "|")
    end repeat
end tell
```

`linesToPrint` is an array of strings

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using a handler from inside an application tell statement, you need to use the terms [of me](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW1) or [my](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW1) to indicate that the term is from your script, and not something that the application needs to do.

Comment: Can you Please Answer this Question:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890369/not-able-to-execute-applescript-within-mail-application